# нарисовать прямоугольник из двух чередующихся символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы, прямоугольники

необходимо нарисовать прямоугольник, стороны которого состоят из двух произвольных чередующихся символов в консоли на python. использую матрицу для этого, выведение просто прямоугольника из одного символа труда не составило, но вот как это сделать с двумя символами, которые не должны повторяться?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам вот это что ли надо? А то вопрос очень размывчатый, вы бы пример привели бы

```
width = 10
height = 7
symbols = '=+o'

print((symbols * width)[:width])

index = width
for i in range(1, height):
    char1 = symbols[index % len(symbols)]
    index += 1
    char2 = symbols[index % len(symbols)]
    index += 1
    print(f'{char1}{" " * (width - 2)}{char2}')

print((symbols * width)[index % len(symbols):width + index % len(symbols)])
```

если нужно чередовать в разных направлениях

```
width = 12
height = 7
symbols = '12345'

print((symbols * width)[:width])

for i in range(1, height):
    char1 = (symbols * height * width)[i % len(symbols)]
    char2 = (symbols * height * width)[(width + i - 1) % len(symbols)]
    print(f'{char1}{" " * (width - 2)}{char2}')

print((symbols * width * height)[height:width + height])
```

сделал также склейку с 3 углами

Comment: эффект тот что нужен, но не три символа, как у вас, а два. Если убираю один из них, в боковых сторонах чередование перестаёт работать

Comment: почему? код универсальный, хоть 100 символов ставь или вы имели в виду, что чередование должно быть не по горизонтали, а для вертикальных линий по вертикали, для горизонтальных - по горизонтали?

Comment: нет, вы всё правильно поняли изначально, чередование должно быть и по вертикали и по горизонтали змейкой. попробуйте сами убрать один из символов, вертикальные становятся сплошными

Comment: так он и будет сплошным - если идет чередование `белый черный белый черный`, то каждый четный у вас пойдет на правую границу (черный), а каждый нечетный - не левую (белый)

Comment: значит, всё-таки, неправильно обьяснил. вертикальные также должны чередоваться как вы сказали в предыдущем комментарии: вертикальные - вертикально, горизонтальные - горизонтально

Comment: я в ответе добавил новый код - так же в нем склейка с 3 углами, по сути это эквивалентно тому что мы двигаемся по периметру